# refresh loader in component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a question about react-router-dom v6
for one of my projects, I've been using **loader** feature in react-router.
but I faced a big problem. actually, I have to show list of online courses in a page. so for /courses route I'm using loader to feed data to that route. in this route I also need to remove an online course. after remove a course I need to refresh my list. but I don't access the loader function in current component. **in other word I need to refresh loader in my component in order to update the online courses**
Is any solution?

I need to resolve my problem

Answer (score -1):

Actually it is better to define the loader function in the same component from where useLoaderdata will be used ao that i always have the access to it.